# C# compare 2 EntityCollections for similarities

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have 2 collections

- List with all Extra Costs from a Training
- List with Extra Costs of A Trainee

I would need to compare and retrieve all extra costs found in both collections.

This is what i tried:

```cs
foreach (var extrakost in opleidingExtraKostResult.Entities)
{
    if (extrakost.Attributes.Values.SequenceEqual(cursistExtraKosts.Entities.First().Attributes.Values))
    {
        EntityCollection similarCollection = new EntityCollection();
        similarCollection.Entities.Add(extrakost);
    }
}
```

The problem I think I am facing is that `cursistExtraKosts.Entities.First().Attributes.Values` is an array of Extra cost entities. So I am comparing an Entity vs an Array of entities?

EDIT: I got it to work like this:

```cs
EntityCollection similarCollection = new EntityCollection();
foreach (var extrakost in opleidingExtraKostResult.Entities)
{
    foreach (var traineeExtraKost in cursistExtraKosts.Entities)
    {
        if (traineeExtraKost.Id==extrakost.Id)
        {
            similarCollection.Entities.Add(extrakost);
        }
    }
}
```

Some small birdie tells me this is not the way to go (bad performance). Please suggest better methods.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve. From the code examples it is not clear what these collections cursistExtraKosts and opleidingExtraKostResult actually are; are these holding rows coming from the same table? If so, why don't you create a query with a join? If not, why do you compare these records by their primary Id?

Comment: Yes they are both from the same table. cursistExtraKosts holds all extraKosts of a person. and opleidingExtraKostResult holds all ExtraKosts of a training. I need those combined to find all extra kosts of a person and also from a specific training. I now compare both collection to know the results. A better way would be to have a join but i have no idea how to do this.